# Apache Pig doesn't respect ELSE statement when value is NULL

Tags: apache-pig

When checking a value in a CASE statement in Apache Pig the ELSE routine is ignored when one of the values in the condition is NULL.

So in the example below, when either A or B is a NULL value then A_equals_B will be NULL in the output rather then 0.

```
input = LOAD '/data/input.csv' USING PigStorage() AS (A:chararray, B:chararray);
output = FOREACH input GENERATE
    CASE
        WHEN A == B THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS A_equalsB;
```

It this by design? What is the best work around for these issues? I add checks for the NULLs separately, but it adds a lot of bloat in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is by design, yes. In Pig, almost every expression dealing with a NULL will result in a NULL, so you should always check for these values in your code. There is a list of what happens with NULLs in [the official documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#nulls).

> **Arithmetic operators:** If either subexpression is null, the resulting expression is null.
>
> - , -, *, /
> - % modulo
> - ? : bincond
> - CASE : case

The best workaround is what you said, checking for NULLs with the `is null` and `is not null` operators. You generate messy lines of code when the possibility of many null values exist but unfortunately there is no other solution at the moment.